# count down to multiple moments, how?

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm creating a site for my neighbor who has a Christmas light show.

The show runs every year from 6 December till 1 January twice an evening: at 6.30pm and at 8.00pm.

We want to add a countdown on the website which says:

> next show: 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)

But how do I do that. When I search for it on the web every one says that I have to use an API for a countdown.

But they just use one date to count down to, so I think I have to write one myself in JavaScript.

Can anyone help with that?

I guess I have to use many `if`/`else` statements, starting with "is the month 1, 12 or something else?", followed by "has it yet been 18.30?" (I want 24-hours) and "has it already been 20.00" and so on.

But is there a better way, because this seems a lot of work to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has a built-in date object that makes dealing with dates and times a bit less manual:

- [MDN documentation for JavaScript's date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

If you supply no arguments to its constructor, it'll give you the current date (according to the end user's computer):

```
var now = new Date();
```

You can set it to a specific date by supplying the year, month (zero-indexed from January), day, and optionally hour, minute and second:

```
var now = new Date();
var first_show = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 11, 6, 18, 30);
```

You can use greater- and less-than comparisons on these date objects to check whether a date is after or before another:

```
var now = new Date();
var first_show = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 11, 6, 18, 30);
alert(now < first_show);// Alerts true (at date of writing)
```

So, you could:

1. Create date objects for the current date, and each show this year (and for the 1st Jan shows next year)
2. Loop through the show dates in chronological order, and
3. Use the first one that's greater than the current date as the basis for your countdown.

Note: you should use something server-side to set `now` with accurate parameters, instead of just relying on `new Date()`, because if the end-user's computer is set to the wrong time, it'll give the wrong result.

Comment: So if I am right, I have to check which of the 52 shows have already been with     var now = new Date(); if(now < document.write(Date.parse("06 Dec 2013 17:30:00 GMT"))     . That might be a lot of work, even if I use a function.

Comment: Yes, although if you put the dates and times of the shows in chronological order in an array called `shows`, then you'd write one `for` loop to do that: `for (var i=0; i<shows.length; i++) { if( now < shows[i] ) { doCountdownForShow(shows[i]); break; } }`.

Comment: And remember: when you're a programmer, there will occasionally be times when, however much you try to avoid it, you do have to do some programming :)

Comment: You could use a `for` loop in your function to create the array of show datetimes too. Loop through the numbers 6 - 31, create two datetimes for each, then create 1 for 1st January, all for the current year. I think `Date.parse()` relies on the locale settings on the user's computer to interpret the date string you pass to it, so I'd advise passing numbers to `new Date()` instead.

Comment: If I want to use a variable outside the function/loop it was created in it won't work, right? Do I have to declare it before I use the loop  or is there another way?

Comment: I have created an array with the values I got from a page I made earlier: 54 times the document.write(Date.parse("06 Dec 2013 17:30:00 GMT")+"<br>"); .

Comment: If you declare a variable inside a function (e.g. `function myfunc() {var myvar = '1';}`), then it won't be accessible outside that function. (Because JavaScript has function scope.) The same is not true for loops.

Comment: If you have further questions, they'd be better asked as new, specific Stack Overflow questions, with example code.

Comment: Thought I did it, but guess what... uploaded it to http://kerstlichtshow.hostingsiteforfree.com/countdown%20demo.html. Can you find my bug? I commented everything so you'll understand. By the way: when I tried to run the page in dreamweaver, it got stack.

Comment: @AxelKöhler: “Can you find my bug?” — nope (not running a free code-fixing service here), but you should ask another Stack Overflow question about it — you’re likely to get a good answer within minutes, and the question might help other people. Check http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask/ if you haven’t already.

Comment: You mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601480/why-doesnt-my-js-countdown-work?noredirect=1#comment25618169_17601480? I posted it in a new question right after I chatted it to you, but because you knew my case, I thought you would know better and I couldn't find a pm-function on this site, so I also wrote it here.

Comment: @AxelKöhler: something like that question, yup. It’s a better question now that you’ve edited it, although it’s easier if you can describe your problem in English was well as just putting code up. Ideally, questions like that should have: 1. What are you trying to achieve? 2. What steps have you taken so far? (Including relevant code) 3. What outcome did you expect from those steps? 4. What outcome are you actually getting?

Comment: By the way, you should edit the second comment on your answer. In that new topic, someone told me that I created an infinite loop, the bit I got from your comment. Not that it's so  bad for me now, but users who are reading my question could get errors. The right code shoud be the same, but than with the first '<' (for loop, condition that has to be true) as an '>'.

Comment: @AxelKöhler: the code in my second comment doesn’t create an infinite loop. Here’s an example using that loop: http://jsfiddle.net/mSSwN/1/ Your loop from you other question creates an infinite loop because it increments the counter variable `i` in the `for` statement (`(var i=0; i<shows.length; i++)`), but then decrements it in the loop body (`var nextShow = --i`), making `i`’s value stay the same in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Yeah you're right the thing I did wrong was the --i. That wasn't even nessesary and made things even worse. Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will count down for 4 hours starting `now()` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = new Date(), element, interval;
limit.setHours(limit.getHours() + 4);
window.onload = function() {
    element = document.getElementById("countdown");
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        if (now.getTime() >= limit.getTime()) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        var diff = limit.getTime() - now.getTime();
        var hours = parseInt(diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        diff = diff % (60 * 60 * 1000);
        minutes = parseInt(diff / (60 * 1000));
        diff = diff % (60 * 1000);
        seconds = parseInt(diff / 1000);
        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        miliseconds = diff % 1000;
        miliseconds = miliseconds.toString().substring(0, 2);
        element.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + miliseconds;
    }, 10);
}
```

See it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BfCVM/)

Comment: Cool, but I have multiple dates to count to, 54 to be exacty.